# Angular multiple observable http calls after one complated

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have multiple services that gets http response from server.

```
export abstract class ServiceBase<T>{
    getAll(){console.log(`${this.url}/${this.endpoint}`)
        return this.http.get<any[]>(`${this.url}/${this.endpoint}`);
    }

    get(id: any){
        return this.http.get<any>(`${this.url}/${this.endpoint}/${id}`);
    }
}

@Injectable()
export class Service1 extends ServiceBase<any> {
    constructor(http: HttpClient) {
        super(http, "http://localhost:60211", "s1");
    }
}

@Injectable()
export class Service2 extends ServiceBase<any> {
    constructor(http: HttpClient) {
        super(http, "http://localhost:60211", "s2");
    }
}


@Injectable()
export class Service3 extends ServiceBase<any> {
    constructor(http: HttpClient) {
        super(http, "http://localhost:60211", "s3");
    }
}
```

And I am using this in application.

```
export class AppComponent {
     s1: {};
     s2: any[];
     s2: any[];
     constructor(service1:Service1, service2:service2, service3:service3){
        service1.get("123").subscribe({       
          next: response => {
            this.s1=response;
            service2.getAll().subscribe({
                    next: response => {
                        this.s2 = response;
                    }
            });
            service3.getAll().subscribe({
                    next: response => {
                        this.s3 = response;
                    }
            })
          }
         })
     }
}
```

But s3 and s2 responses does not come from server. Is this this usage is false? But when I run service from postman, service is working.

Comment: Nested subscriptions are not a good technique and are often considered to be an "anti-pattern". They are just about impossible to unsubscribe from and often don't run when you expect them to. You are better off using forkJoin or one of the high-order mapping operators such as switchMap or mergeMap.

Comment: @DeborahK, I have not use forkJoin, I am new at rxjs. can you write a shor answer?

Comment: Done! See below.

Answer (score 2):

You need pipable operators `switchMap` and `combineLatest` to achieve what you want.

It would look something like this:

```
service1.get("123").pipe(
    switchMap(() => combineLatest(service2.getAll(), service3.getAll())),
).subscribe(([service2Data, servoce3Data]) => {
    // do your stuff
});
```

Comment: Better to use forJoin. combineLatest internally uses concat, so runs observables in sequence, one by one. And forkJoin runs observables in parallel, at the same time.

Comment: @FedorSaenko I agree with `forkJoin` being the better choice for http calls that only emit once but `combineLatest` doesn't use `concat` internally and also runs the inner observables in parallel.

Comment: @fridoo can you please tell more why is `forkJoin` better for http calls?

Comment: http calls by the HttpClient emit once and then complete so you don't need the feature of `combineLatest` to emit multiple times. By using `forkJoin` you indicate that you expect the inner observables to complete and only want one final emission when all inner observables are done. It's like a contract you make with yourself or other developers you work with and can prevent bugs / unexpected behaviour if the code of those inner observables is changed later on. `forkJoin` is all you need so why use a more complex function.

Comment: One of you here ( @FedorSaenko ) want to propose an answer with forkJoin since you were the first to mention it? Otherwise I will. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of a `forkJoin`. To ensure the syntax was correct and that it worked, this is from my code (instead of from the OPs code).

```
  // Suppliers for the selected product
  // Only gets the suppliers it needs
  // switchMap here instead of mergeMap so quickly clicking on the items 
  // cancels prior requests.
  selectedProductSuppliers$ = this.selectedProduct$
    .pipe(
      filter(selectedProduct => Boolean(selectedProduct)),
      switchMap(selectedProduct =>
        forkJoin(selectedProduct.supplierIds.map(supplierId => this.http.get<Supplier>(`${this.suppliersUrl}/${supplierId}`)))
      ),
      tap(suppliers => console.log('product suppliers', JSON.stringify(suppliers)))
    );
```

This code receives notification any time a new product is selected (`this.selectedProduct`)

It then pipes the selection through a set of operations:

- It filters out a null selectedProduct (such as when the page is first displayed and the user has not yet selected a product)
- It uses switchMap so if the user picks product 1, no product 2, no product 3, in quick succession, it will only emit product 3.
- It uses forkJoin to take each supplierId defined for the selected product and use it to get the supplier detail data and then merges all of the suppliers into one array and emits that array.

`selectedProductSuppliers` is then an `Observable<Supplier[]>` and emits the array of suppliers for the selected product.

You can find the complete set of code here: https://github.com/DeborahK/Angular-RxJS